# Is there a ring isomorphism between $M_n(D)$ and $M_m(D)$ where $n\neq m$ and $D$ is a division ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is there a ring isomorphism between $M_n(D)$ and $M_m(D)$ where $n\neq m$ and $D$ is a division ring?

I know that this is impossible if we talk about left $D$-vector space homomorphisms (because of dimension over $D$ must be the same).
What if we think about just a ring isomorphism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*No, this cannot exist:* You can recover $n$ from the isomorphism class of the ring $M_n(D)$ as the number of irreducible summands in the decomposition of the regular $M_n(D)$ module.

*Note:* This argument is invalid in the categorical context, i.e. when talking about invariants of the *module categories*, because there's no canonical notion of *regular* module. Indeed, as you'll probably know, $M_n(D)$ and $D$ have equivalent module categories.

Comment: @Antonio Pupillo: Do you have questions or can this be closed?

Comment: That is absolutely clear. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AntonioPupillo You're welcome :) Can this be closed then?

Comment: Yes, sure! thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

(This is related to the same idea Hanno is using, but I like to say it this way.)

$M_n(D)$, as a right module over itself, has a composition series of length $n$, and the same is true for $m$. But the length of the composition series is uniquely defined, and isomorphic rings are going to have identical lattices of right ideals, so $m\neq n$ is not possible.