# Why does $M_n(D)$ ($D$ being a division ring) as a right module over itself have a composition series of length $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

Why does $M_n(D)$ as a right module over itself have a composition series of length $n$? (Here $D$ is a division ring).

I’ve found this statement in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2208475/923279) but I couldn’t figure out the reason and I don’t have the minimum reputation to use the comments to ask the OP. I’m just starting to learn about rings and modules so please try to keep in mind that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, observe the set $D^n$ with matrix multiplication by elements of $M_n(D)$ on the right is a simple $M_n(D)$ module.

Then define $R_i$ to be the subset of matrices which are zero except on row $i$.  Each of these sets is a right ideal of $M_n(D)$, and moreover is isomorphic to $D^n$ as a $M_n(D)$ module.

At this point you've expressed $M_n(D)=\oplus_{i=1}^n R_i$ in terms of simple submodules, and from there it is obvious what the length $n$ composition series is, namely, the one whose terms are $\oplus_{i=1}^k R_i$ for $k=1,\ldots, n$.

Comment: Thank you! By $D^n$ you just mean $n$ times the cartesian product of $D$ with itself, right?

Comment: @kejihiv Yes. I do.