# How to construct an isomorphism such that $I_j \cong D^n$, where $I_j$ is the subring of $M_n(D)$ all of whose columns except the $j$-th are zero

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, modules

If $D$ is a division ring and $R=M_n(D)$ is the $n\times n$ matrix ring over $D$, then $R=\bigoplus_j I_j$ where $I_j$ is the subring of $R$ all of whose columns except the $j$-th are zero. My question is, how can we construct [an isomorphism such that $I_j \cong D^n$ for each $j$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4128179/328767) (where $D^n$ is the cartesian product of $D$ with itself, $n$ times)? What would be its explicit form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$D^n = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_n \end{pmatrix} :\, d_1,\dots\, d_n\in D\right\}.$$
Then $D^n$ is an $R$ - module with multiplication given by
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\alpha_{11} & \alpha_{12} & \dots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \\
\alpha_{n1} &  & \alpha_{nn} 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
d_1 \\ \vdots \\ d_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Similarly,
$$I_{j}= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & \alpha_{1j} & \dots & 0\\
0 & \dots & \alpha_{2j} & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots &\vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
0 & \dots& \alpha_{nj} &\dots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
:\, \alpha_{1j},\,\alpha_{2j},\,\dots,\, \alpha_{nj}\in D\right\}\subseteq R,
$$
is a **left** ideal of $R$. Now, let $F:I_j\to D^n$ given by
$$F\left(\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \dots & \alpha_{1j} & \dots & 0\\
0 & \dots & \alpha_{2j} & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots &\vdots & \ddots& \vdots\\
0 & \dots& \alpha_{nj} &\dots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\right)=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ \alpha_{nj} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now check that this correspondence is an isomorphism of $R$ - modules. I.e. it is an isomorphism between the $R$ - modules $I_j$ and $D^n$.